# send post request with parameters (data) using promise - pure javascript

Tags: javascript, php, promise, es6-promise

If I use a simple post xhr request its working to send post parameters:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "example url";
var params = "limit=2";
http.open("post", url);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
       alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

But If I use promise with parameters (data) then I get undefined index php error, with promise I cant send parameters? or I miss something...

```
  function postAjaxCall(url, data) {
  // return a new promise.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // do the usual XHR stuff
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('post', url);

    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status == 200) {
      resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };

    // handle network errors
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    // make the request
    req.send(data);
    //same thing if i hardcode like
    //req.send("limit=2");
  });
};
```

and I make the request

```
postAjaxCall('example url', "limit=2").then(
        function(response) {
          document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = response;
        },
        function(error) {
          console.error("Failed!", error);
        });
```

Comment: `var url = "example url";` Is that really in your code or did you change it for posting it here?

Comment: I changed it, removed the sensitive data...

Comment: Can you post the exact PHP-Error

Comment: Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network and see what is actually sent and how it differs from alternate approach. Some basic debugging is needed

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: limit in /var/www ... on line ...
echo ($_POST['limit']); - that is in php, as I said the first code is working ok

Comment: @charlietfl how to inspect the post request? the post request parameters?

Comment: I see that If I use the promise version the parameter is not sent...

Comment: @almostokey this error/notice come from PHP not from JavaScript

Comment: @ponury-kostek what do you mean? I know that, If I use the post request without promise then I can send the parameters, and no php error will be, but If I use the post request with promise then no parameters are sent - > and will be a php error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check your request header at your server side, you will see that your request was sent as text/plain. To make PHP see the request as a $_POST you will need to set the request header to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', which should come after xhr.open() and before xhr.onload. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started shows a basic Ajax usage.

```
function postAjaxCall(url, data) { 
    // return a new promise. 
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    // do the usual XHR stuff 
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('post', url); 
//NOW WE TELL THE SERVER WHAT FORMAT OF POST REQUEST WE ARE MAKING 
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.onload = function() { 
    if (req.status == 200) { 
        resolve(req.response); 
    } else { 
        reject(Error(req.statusText)); 
        } 
    }; 
    // handle network errors 
req.onerror = function() { 
    reject(Error("Network Error")); 
}; // make the request 
req.send(data); 
    //same thing if i hardcode like //req.send("limit=2"); 
}); 
};
```

Comment: yeah, thank you I figured out in meantime, now I am using fetch to get data